# Netbeans/Xdebug displays only some local variables in functions

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans-8.2

I've been debugging a PHP script on my local server using NetBeans and XDebug. Even with `xdebug.show_local_vars = 1` set in php.ini Netbeans will only occasionally display local arrays in a function.

For example, in a minimal script like this:

```
<?php
test();
function test() {
  $dow = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
  $tod = ['AM', 'PM', 'EVE'];
  $mat = ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
}
```

I can view `$mat` in Netbean's variables window but not the other two. Changing the array names makes no difference.

Any thoughts on why `$mat` shows up but not the others?

Comment: Are you saying this exact script works as you suggest, because when I run it in NetBeans 10.0 I can see all 3 arrays and there contents in the `Variables` window

Comment: Although I have `xdebug.show_local_vars=9` but cannot remember why

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Xdebug regards any non-zero value here as true. Yes, it works just as I describe on my local server. I'm actually running Netbeans 8.2 (on Win10). Perhaps this is the difference between us?

Comment: Could be OPCache (quite likely; remember: it is disabled for CLI by default .. so debugging the same via CLI or web may show diff results (in terms of "showing up variable in a list")). P.S. In your code sample, those arrays are not used anywhere in a function, so may have been "optimized". You can alwasy tell Xdebug to log all communications with debug client and see what data it sends to (or receives from) NetBeans.

Comment: @LazyOne: Good point about optimisation. I should have mentioned that I originally met the problem in a working function where the array variables are used but got the same result.

Comment: @magnol I'm using PhpStorm and saw questions here on SO about similar behaviour. So it must be PHP / OPCache thing. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842099/local-variables-not-shown-when-opcache-is-enabled-while-debugging-with-xdebug